# rackup server with ability to stop and restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rack

i'm planning to add some tasks to my capistrano recipes file to give ability for admins to remote start/stop/restart [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) server. But if for start i can use something like

```
  desc "Start private_pub server"
  task :start do
    run "cd #{current_path};rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -D"
  end
```

i cannot find any documentation how to stop or restart rackup server. i see option

```
  -P, --pid FILE           file to store PID (default: rack.pid)
```

but maybe use kill command to stop server - not good idea?

Answer (score 2):

I found this while searching for the same solution.

[gist.github.com/3197633](https://gist.github.com/3197633)

basically while starting the process you have it write the pid number to a file in /tmp/pids and then when you go to stop it you read that file and it runs kill -9 ...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e correct in that using `kill -9` is a bad idea. This can lead to uneccesary loss of data, and as I understand it is recommended to use `kill 2` or `kill -INT` which is equivalent to hitting 'control-c' and should close a normal server for you. I personally have started managing my servers with the God gem by TPW. Here is the script I use for running a local 'geminabox' server, for instance:

```
God.watch do |w|
w.name = 'gemserver'
    w.dir = '/usr/local/gemserver'
    w.pid_file = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.god/pids/#{w.name}.pid"
    ru = File.expand_path `which rackup`
    w.start = "#{ru} -D #{w.dir}/config.ru -P #{w.pid_file}"
    # w.stop = lambda { Process.kill(3, `lsof -i :9292`.chomp.to_i) }
    w.behavior :clean_pid_file
    w.keepalive
end
```